# How can I install git on RHEL 6?

Tags: git, rhel6, epel

I'm trying to install Git on a RHEL6 development server, I have experience with Ubuntu but this is my first time working with RHEL (I'm a developer trying to fill in for a recently departed Linux Sysadmin).

I've set up two additional repos (EPEL and IUS) for other packages needed for a Magento install.  Output of yum repolist:

```
[root@box]# yum repolist
Loaded plugins: product-id, security, subscription-manager
Updating certificate-based repositories.
repo id              repo name                                        status
epel                 Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64   7,841
ius                  IUS for RHEL 6Server - x86_64                    135
```

Most of what I've read indicates a simple 'yum install git' should work with EPEL enabled, but I get the dreaded

```
[root@box]# yum install git
Loaded plugins: product-id, security, subscription-manager
Updating certificate-based repositories.
Setting up Install Process
No package git available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Same goes for git-daemon, etc.

I've tracked down a number of git RPMs such as [this one at repoforge](http://pkgs.repoforge.org/git/) but they require a train of dependencies that seems to never end.

I've also toyed with [compiling it manually](http://ejvyas.blogspot.com/2012/03/installing-git-on-oracle-linuxrhel.html) but the rabbit hole to get make working seems to go even deeper.

I'm convinced there's a simple oversight somewhere keeping me from being able to install from the EPEL repo, but I'm a rookie at all this.  Thanks in advance for help/pointers/additional resources.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a problem with your YUM repo for the actual distribution... It doesn't appear as though you have a "base" repository, based on your `yum repolist` command output. I suppose [you could just download it](http://mirror.anl.gov/pub/centos/6.3/os/x86_64/Packages/git-1.7.1-2.el6_0.1.x86_64.rpm) as well...

```
[root@Kitteh ~]# yum repolist
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: xt.lol.net
 * epel: mirror.cogentco.com
 * extras: xt.lol.net
 * update: xt.lol.net
repo id                             repo name                                                                 status
base                                CentOS-6 - Base                                                           6346
epel                                Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64                            7858
extras                              CentOS-6 - Extras                                                            4
rpmforge                            Red Hat Enterprise 6 - RPMforge.net - dag                                 4445
update                              CentOS-6 - Updates                                                         665
```

...and proof that GIT is part of the base repository...

```
[root@Kitteh ~]# yum info git
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: xt.lol.net
 * epel: mirror.cogentco.com
 * extras: xt.lol.net
 * update: xt.lol.net
Installed Packages
Name        : git
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 1.7.1
Release     : 2.el6_0.1
Size        : 15 M
Repo        : installed
From repo   : anaconda-CentOS-201112091719.x86_64
Summary     : Fast Version Control System
URL         : http://git-scm.com/
License     : GPLv2
Description : Git is a fast, scalable, distributed revision control system with an
            : unusually rich command set that provides both high-level operations
            : and full access to internals.
            : 
            : The git rpm installs the core tools with minimal dependencies.  To
            : install all git packages, including tools for integrating with other
            : SCMs, install the git-all meta-package.
```

Comment: This definitely makes sense; I've had to piecemeal the RHEL server with practically no prior experience with repos/rpms.  Blame Aptitude for making it too easy elsewhere.
In /etc/yum.repos.d/ I have the following: rhel-source.repo, epel-testing.repo, epel.repo, ius.repo, redhat.repo.  
The epel* and ius are ones I created manually, but the redhat and rhel-source were already present after the server install.  What would be the best method to ensure they're enabled, assuming those are the base repos you mention?

Comment: The RPM you linked is similar to others I've tried; missing dependencies (perl-Git, etc)... could this also be because the base repo is misconfigured?

Comment: Do you have a RHEL subscription on this server?

Comment: I believe that we do, yes.

Comment: To fix the repo subscriptions, go to the RHN management page for this server and subscribe it to the appropriate channel. Then run `rhn-check`. If that fails, just open a ticket with RH. You have support, after all!

Comment: @ewwhite Turned out the base repos were missing because of a bad install without registering the RHEL key, hence no subscription/etc.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: @MikeyB Same for you sir, thanks for guiding me through the woods.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
# rpm -q git
```

if this won't return anything, try following

```
# yum clean all
# yum install git
```

also make run this to see what's included/excluded in your repos:

```
# grep -iE "^exclude|^include" /etc/yum.repos.d/*.repo
/etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo:exclude=nagios-*
#
```

UPDATE: (aka another way)

```
# rpm -ivh http://pkgs.repoforge.org/git/git-1.7.11.3-1.el6.rfx.x86_64.rpm
#
```

Comment: No dice on the clean/install attempt, still no git package found.
No grep result for either exclude/include either.

Comment: look at updated section

Comment: Thanks, but same outcome as downloading/installing the RPM directly (IE: failed dependencies)

Comment: Which dependencies exactly? (install it too)

Comment: Too numerous to list, but the issue was the base Repo was missing due to a faulty install.  Thanks for trying!