# How to install git-daemon on red hat enterprise 6

Tags: linux, git, rhel6

I need to install git-daemon on Red Hat enterprise Linux 6.2, with http support. What are the correct package to install? It is necessary to create a specific user or group? I'm looking for a simple solution with yum perhaps

I already checked this answer
[How can I install git on RHEL 6?](https://serverfault.com/questions/433807/how-can-i-install-git-on-rhel-6)

but seems to be referred to git client only

Answer (score 4):

I would be remiss if I didn't point out the spectacular lack of research in your question, but here's your answer:

`yum install git-daemon`